# About knockout.js visible binding and javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js and am fairly new to it as we all javascript.

So here's my issue. I have a radio button, which when clicked, has to display a div block.

Here's the code for the radio button:

```
<label class="radio inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="advanced" name="chooseMe" value="chooseMe" data-bind="checked: qrType" />
                    ChooseMe
</label>
```

Here's the div:

```
<div  class = "salaryBlock" data-bind="visible: qrType() == 'chooseMe'"><input type="text" id="" placeholder="Salary" /></div>
```

I have a separate viewmodel file which should contain the javascript method.

Here's the method:
       `$(function () {
        var rbViewModel = {
            qrType: ko.observable('plaintext')
        };
        ko.applyBindings(rbViewModel);
    });`

**I have two questions: **
1) How do I  tie this function to the div tag with the class name? I am not sure how to  write the code. Should it be `$(.salaryBlock).function(){ var rbViewModel = {
            qrType: ko.observable('plaintext')
        };
        ko.applyBindings(rbViewModel);
    });`
`

2) Is my code in html for binding correct? Please let me know.

I would appreciate your help guys.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine, could you clarify what you want to do? Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fx6Gn/1/

Comment: @Boss, that's a good question. To be honest, that' where I am stuck. I would like the div tag to show when you select the radio and hide when you disselect. I am not sure how to go about writing that.

Comment: @7zark, I have a separate javascript file. Which means, I will have to tie my javascript code with the div tag so that when the radio button is clicked, the div tag appears, and when it is disselected, it is hidden. Hence, something along the lines of $(.salaryBlock)...

Comment: The fiddle demonstrates a "separate Javascript file" if you include that JS via a script tag.  Please explain what end-functionality the fiddle is not doing.

Comment: @7zark, I think the example doesnt toggle the div. However, Srikanth's(the bottom answer) captures that. I just wanted to know how to tie the javascript code with the div tag. You mentioned that the javascript code in jsfiddle is on a separate file. So, that captures it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kyQcF/1/

You dont need to bind the view model using `$function`.

Alternatively, you could do what @7zark7's fiddle does. Basically, you need to ensure that when your js file loads, the viewmodel is initialized and ko.applybindings is called with that view model.

Comment: ,thanks for your help. what do you mean when you say "make sure view model is initialized"?

Comment: @Stranger, what I meant was, since you are loading your viewmodel through an external javascript file, the inclusion of the file in the view should ensure that the view is able to see the viewmodel. Only then the data-bind will happen without having to trigger another event.